Using a list of colors for a bar chart in Altair
I am trying to provide a list of colors to bind to the bar marks in Altair, similar to how matplotlib's pyplot.bar(color=list_of_colors) can specify the color for each individual bar, like in the example here. Additionally, I am also using the edgecolor attribute in matplotlib. Is it possible to do both these things in Altair as well? If so, example code would be great.

You can use the list of colors to create a column that contains the raw value of the color you want to use and set .scale(None) as per this section of the docs..
The equivalent to edgecolor is called stroke which you use the same way as color.

Thanks @joelostblom, that works! Would you say such customizations in Altair are integral and extensible part of the API, or are they the exceptions? Does the underlying "grammar" support/encourage such patterns or is it a sign to go a level lower to vega or something like d3, maybe? It feels a bit strange to have additional columns to store the color and stroke values (essentially tripling the size of a dataframe I guess), hence wondering how such programming fits in the altair ecosystem.

Sorry, just to correct myself: not triping, but more than doubling the size of the dataframe (because in my case, the stroke has the same value for all the data).

@MohitChawla If the stroke has the same value for all the data, you can use the stroke parameter in the mark instead as in this example https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/natural_disasters.html. When you mentioned a list of colors, I thought there were different colors for some of the rows.

@joelosblom, thanks will check it out. The colors are indeed different for each object - although always either black or white.

@MohitChawla Oh I see, it sounds like you maybe want to set the range of the color domain as in this example https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/customization.html#color-domain-and-range? That would just require typing each color name once and not add anything to the df.

@joelosblom cool, will test that out too. Just to be on the same page, I do require that for each element of the data in all rows, I individually specify which should be black, which should be white. So if row1 = [1,2,3] and row2 = [4,5,6], the color sequence would be individually defined...so colors_row1 = ["black", "white", "white] etc.
